# js changes to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am searching for a way to get notified when a js is changing/mutating the page's DOM, and know which js caused the change.
How can I achieve this? Is there a way to do so using Java? In JavaScript? Any other way?
Thanks,
Inbar.

Comment: hm ... i could manipulate such a script as well. then it would be useless. for what reason you would like to know this. maybe there is a better way of avoiding your problem.
if it is only your js which you would like to track, just log what u are doing..

Comment: Do you want this in order to debug a script or in order to implement some functionality? This type of debugging is build into both firebug and webkits javascript debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add an event listener to listen for Mutation events.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Update: I see from other answers that there might be problems with IE support. See [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)